# How do I use an arduino as an LED controller?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm a total C++ newbie, but I recently got an arduino and I'm doing my first project with it. I may be jumping into the deep end here, but I've got some experience with electronics already. I also have some experience with python.

I want to make a fancy interior lighting setup using two of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CDTEKAG) led strips and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D8KOZF4) arduino starter kit.

I need to make a whole bunch of presets that can be quickly activated using the IR remote included with the kit.

I need to be able to split the strips into individual zones , which I can use to easily set the presets. Maybe I want preset1 to be the ceiling lights a dark blue at 50% brightness and the window lights an orange at 25% brightness.

I know that to achieve this I want every button on the remote to call a different function. I've written some [Psuedocode](https://pastebin.com/Uq501it2) and I'd like some advice on the best way to learn how to implement this on an arduino.

I really need help with the software side of this project, the hardware side is all good.

disclaimer: I haven't touched coding since high school, so my psuedocode is probably trash. I just hope it's vaguely understandable

```
//Psuedocode attempt to make an LED thingy


// Importing needed libraries
Import fastled
Import IRremote

define num_led 300
define data_pin 5

// defining various zones. Zone 1 = Under cabinet, Zone 2 = Around window etc.
Global zone1 = num_led [0:24]
Global zone2 = num_led [24:172]
Global zone3 = num_led [173:277]
Global zone4 = num_led [278:299]

Def preset1()
    for led in zone1:
        ledRGB = (160, 0, 210)
    for led in zone2:
        ledRGB = (120, 0, 24)
    for led in zone3:
        ledRGB = (0, 0, 0)
    for led in zone4:
        ledRGB = (100,100,100)
// Make a whole bunch more of these normal presets

Def preset6()
    for led in zone1:
        do cool fastled animation
    for led in zone2:
        do different fastled animation
    for led in zone3:
        ledRGB = (0, 0, 0)
    for led in zone4:
        ledRGB = (0, 0, 0)

// Make a whole bunch more of these fancy presets

Def BrightnessUp()
    i = 0
    for num_led in zone1 and zone2 and zone3 and zone4:
        if i in ledRGB > 0: //This is to minimise colour shift. Any RGB channel set at 0 won’t increase.
            i = i+10
        else:
            return

// Similar for brightness down
        


void setup() { 
    
    FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
{



//The following is mostly copy pasted C++ code with modifications 
//It works to understand the IR remote inputs and call functions based on input

const int RECV_PIN = 7;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
unsigned long key_value = 0;

void setup(){
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
}

void loop(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
 
        if (results.value == 0XFFFFFFFF)
          results.value = key_value;

        switch(results.value)
          case 0xFF30CF:
          Serial.println("1");
     Call preset1()
          break ;
          case 0xFF18E7:
          Serial.println("2");
     Call preset2()
          break ;
          case 0xFF7A85:
          Serial.println("3");
     Call preset3()
          break ;
         //ETC for every number on remote
      case 0xFFE01F:
          Serial.println("-");
     Call BrigtnessDown()
          break ;  
          case 0xFFA857:
          Serial.println("+");
     Call BrightnessUp()
          break ;  
     
        }
        key_value = results.value;
        irrecv.resume(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: The intent is clear from your pseudo-code.  Since your question is:
> I'd like some advice on the best way to learn how to implement this on an arduino

Don't try to code everything at once.  Start by building core blocks and prototypes:
- Get it to respond to IR to control just one LED
- Build a simple animation with timer and loops updating LEDs as you need (separate from any IR code)
- Look at proper ways to change brightness (there are guides and formulas). Simple increment of +10 will probably not produce result you want (as it will not be proportional).  
Nice project, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Steps to be followed are

1. Install the FastLED Library from GitHub: [FastLED Lib](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED)
2. Install the IRremote Library from GitHub: [IRremote Lib](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote)
3. Import it to your Arduino library folder via Arduino IDE: [Importing a .zip Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries#importing-a-zip-library)

---

Here is a basic structure of the program which we will require.

```cpp
#include "FastLED.h"
#include "IRremote.h"
#define DATA_PIN 5   // digital pin of your arduino
#define NUM_LEDS 300

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

//Zones array
int zone1[2] = {0, 24};    //For zone1: Start,End
int zone2[2] = {25, 172};  //For zone2: Start,End
int zone3[2] = {173, 277}; //For zone3: Start,End
int zone4[2] = {278, 299}; //For zone4: Start,End

// For IR receiver
const int RECV_PIN = 3; // Hardware specs allows 3 or 9 pin to be used for ATmega328p
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  //Setup for FastLED
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

  //Setup for IRremote
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); //LED_BUILTIN is the inbuild led on Arduino UNO at Pin13
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  irrecv.blink13(true); // Enable blinking the LED when during reception
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    switch (results.value) {
      case 0xFF30CF:
        Serial.println("1");
        preset1();
        break;
      case 0xFF18E7:
        Serial.println("2");
        //preset2();  //TODO: Complete this preset2
        break;
      case 0xFF7A85:
        Serial.println("3");
        //preset3(); //TODO: Complete this preset3
        break;
      //ETC for every number on remote
      case 0xFFE01F:
        Serial.println("-");
        brightnessDown();
        break;
      case 0xFFA857:
        Serial.println("+");
        brightnessUp();
        break;
      default:
        Serial.println("Not Understood.");
        break;
    }
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
  delay(100);
}

void preset1()
{
  //Zone 1
  for (int i = zone1[0]; i <= zone1[1]; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB(160, 0, 210);
  }

  //Zone 2
  for (int i = zone2[0]; i <= zone2[1]; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB(120, 0, 24);
  }

  //Zone 3
  for (int i = zone3[0]; i <= zone3[1]; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  }

  //Zone 4
  for (int i = zone4[0]; i <= zone4[1]; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB(100, 100, 100);
  }

  //To set the LEDs
  FastLED.show();
}

void brightnessUp()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    if (leds[i].r > 0)
      leds[i].r = leds[i].r + 10;
    if (leds[i].g > 0)
      leds[i].g = leds[i].g + 10;
    if (leds[i].b > 0)
      leds[i].b = leds[i].b + 10;
  }
  //To set the LEDs
  FastLED.show();
}

void brightnessDown()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    if (leds[i].r > 10)
      leds[i].r = leds[i].r - 10;
    if (leds[i].g > 10)
      leds[i].g = leds[i].g - 10;
    if (leds[i].b > 10)
      leds[i].b = leds[i].b - 10;
  }
  //To set the LEDs
  FastLED.show();
}
```

*Note: This code this created with the help of Pseudo-code provided and the logic implemented in it, you may have to change certain things in order for it to produce best results.*